# How do I integrate $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I integrate  $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}\text{?}$$

I know it's trig sub. Please I need help with this. Please provide all steps with good explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with $$\frac{3x}{\sqrt{15}}=\tan u$$ so that $$\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}{\sqrt{15}}=\sec u.$$ With 
$$dx=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}\sec^2 u du$$ we get

$$\begin{align}
\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}dx&=\int\frac{\frac{15}{9}\tan^2u}{\sqrt{15}\sec u}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}\sec^2 u du\\
&=\frac{15}{27}\int\tan^2u\sec udu\\
&=\frac{5}{9}\int(\sec^2u-1)\sec u du\\
&=\frac{5}{9}\int(\sec^3u-\sec u)du\\
&=\frac{5}{9}\bigg[\frac{\sec u\tan u}{2}+\frac{\ln|\sec u+\tan u|}{2}-\ln|\sec u+\tan u|\bigg]+C\\
&=\frac{5}{18}\bigg[\sec u\tan u-\ln|\sec u+\tan u|\bigg]+C\\
&=\frac{5}{18}\bigg[\frac{(\sqrt{9x^2+15})3x}{15}-\ln\bigg|\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+15}+3x}{\sqrt{15}} \bigg|\bigg]+C
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

If we let
$$ x = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{3} \tan u \qquad \qquad dx =  \frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}\sec^2 u \, du $$
Then we see
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+15}} \, dx &= \int \frac{\frac{15}{9}\tan^2 u}{\sqrt{15\tan^2 u+15}} \frac{\sqrt{15}}{3}\sec^2 u \, du \\
&= \frac{5}{9} \int \frac{\sec^2 u \tan^2 u}{\sec u} du \\
&= \frac{5}{9} \int \sec u \tan^2 u \, du \\
&= \frac{5}{9} \int \sec u (\sec^2 u - 1) \, du \\
&= \frac{5}{9} \int (\sec^3 u - \sec u) \, du \\
&= \frac{5}{9} \left[\frac{1}{2}\sec u \tan u + \frac{1}{2} \ln \lvert \sec u + \tan u \rvert - \ln \lvert \sec u + \tan u \rvert \right] + C \\
&= \frac{5}{18}\sec u \tan u - \frac{5}{18}\ln \lvert \sec u + \tan u \rvert + C
\end{align*}
If we imagine the following right triangle:

[image]

we see that:
$$ \tan u = \frac{3x}{\sqrt{15}} \qquad\Longleftrightarrow \qquad \sec u = \frac{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}{\sqrt{15}} $$
so
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+15}} \, dx &= \frac{1}{18}x\sqrt{9x^2+15} - \frac{5}{18}\ln \lvert 3x + \sqrt{9x^2+15} \rvert + C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

To do a trigonometric substitution, you will need
$$
\sqrt{(\text{variable})^2 + 1} = \sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1} = \sqrt{\sec^2\theta} = \sec\theta.
$$
So write
$$
\sqrt{9x^2+15} = \sqrt{15} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{9x^2}{15} + 1} = \sqrt{15} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{3x^2} 5 + 1}.
$$
Then $\tan\theta = x\sqrt{\dfrac 3 5}$ and $\sec^2\theta\,d\theta = \sqrt{\dfrac 3 5} \  dx$  and $x^2 = \dfrac 5 3 \tan\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint write $x^2=\frac {1}{9}(9x^2+15-15) $. Now separate $9x^2+15,-15$. Now you have standard formulae for both $\sqrt {a^2+x^2},\frac {1}{\sqrt {a^2+x^2} } $

Answer (score 0):

**Method**$\#1:$

$$3I=\dfrac{3x^2}{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}=\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+5/3}}=\dfrac{x^2+\dfrac53-\dfrac53}{\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac53}}=\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac53}-\dfrac53\cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac53}}$$

Now use $(1),(8)$ of [this](http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ11/integ11.html)

**Method**$\#2:$

Integrating by parts, $$\int x\cdot\dfrac x{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}dx=x\int\dfrac x{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}dx-\int\left(\dfrac{dx}{dx}\cdot\int\dfrac x{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}dx\right)dx$$

Now for $\displaystyle\int\dfrac x{\sqrt{9x^2+15}}dx,$ set $\sqrt{9x^2+15}=u$